# How to optimize rendering of dynamic geomtry?

Tags: c++, opengl, game-development

As i know batching and instancing is used for decreasing draw-calls amount for static meshes.But what about dynamic meshes?How can i optimize amount of draw calls for them? Instancing and batching
create big overhead because you need to recalculate position with cpu every frame.Or it is better to draw dynamic meshes with separate draw calls?

Comment: If your object is dynamic, don't you have a new set of vertices in each frame anyway? Or are you actually talking about static geometry with a dynamic transformation?

Comment: Frustum cull to decide if it needs to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few performance considerations to keep in mind:

1. Every `glDraw..()` comes with some overhead, so you want to minimize those. That's one reason that instancing is such a performance boon. (Better cache behavior is another.)
2. Host-to-device data transfers (`glBufferData()`) are even slower than draw calls. So, we try to keep data on the GPU (vertex buffers, index buffers, textures) rather than transmitting it each frame.

In your case, there are a couple of ways to get performant dynamic meshes.

- Fake it. Do you really need dynamic meshes - specifically, one where you must generate new mesh data? Or, can you achieve the same thing via transforms in your shaders?
- Generate the mesh on the GPU. This could be done in a compute shader (for best performance) or in geometry and/or tessellation shaders. This comes with its own overhead, but, since everything happening on the GPU, you aren't hit with the much more expensive `glDraw...()` or host-GPU copies.

- Note that geometry shaders are relatively slow, but they're still faster than copying a new vertex + index buffer from the CPU to the GPU. *

- If your "dynamic" mesh has a finite number of states, just keep them all on the GPU and switch between them as necessary.
- If this were another API such as Vulkan, you could potentially generate the mesh in a separate thread and transfer it to the GPU *while* drawing other things. That is a very complex topic, as is just about everything relating to the explicit graphics APIs.

Comment: For the last point, there may be OpenGL extensions that allow sharing memory between the CPU and GPU. They may be platform specific though and you then become responsible to synchronization